# perl Regular expression matching repeating words

Tags: regex, perl

a regular expression that matches any line of input that has the same word repeated 
two or more times consecutively in a row. Assume there is one space between consecutive 
words

```
if($line!~m/(\b(\w+)\b\s){2,}/{print"No match\n";}
    {   print "$`";       #print out first part of string
        print "<$&>";     #highlight the matching part
        print "$'";       #print out the rest
    }
```

This is best i got so far,but there is something wrong
correct me if i am wrong

`\b` start with a word boundary

`(\w+)` followed by one word or more words

`\b`end with a word boundary

`\s` then a space

`{2,}` check if this thing repeat 2 or more times

what's wrong with my expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for: `(?:\b(\w+)\b) (?:\1(?: |$))+`

Also, don't use `\s` when you're just looking for spaces as it's possible you'll match a newline or some other whitespace character.  Simple spaces aren't delimiters or special characters in regex, so it's fine to just type the space.  You can use `[ ]` if you want it to be more visually apparent.

Comment: Would you mind explain this expression for me ? I don't quite understand the second part

Comment: The second part starts with `\1` which is a reference to the first capturing group (stuff contained in `()`) in the regex.  That means it tells the regex to "remember" what it found with `(\w)`, then look for it again where the `\1` is.  After that is a non-capturing group (using `(?:)`) that looks for either a normal space or the end of the string.  This whole 2nd half of the pattern is surrounded by its own capturing group, which is used so that it can be quantified as a whole with `+` (if it weren't in a group, then the `+` would only apply to `(?: |$)`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried CAustin's answer in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and the results were not what I would expect. Also, no need for all the non-capturing groups.

My regex:

```
(\b(\w+))( \2)+
```

Word-boundary, followed by (1 or more word characters)[group 2], followed by one or more of: space, group 2.

This next one replaces the space with `\s+`, generalizing the separation between the words to be 1 or more of any kind of white-space:

```
(\b(\w+))(\s+\2)+
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually checking to see if it's the SAME word that's repeating.  To do that, you need to use a captured backreference:

```
if ($line =~ m/\b(\w+)(?:\s\1){2,}\b/) {
     print "matched '$1'\n";
}
```

Also, anytime you're testing a regular expression, it's helpful if you create a list of examples to work with.  The following demonstrates one way of doing that using the `__DATA__` block

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ m/\b(\w+)(?:\s\1){2,}/) {
        print "matched '$1'\n";
    } else {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
foo foo
foo bar foo
foo foo foo
```

Outputs

```
no match
no match
matched 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using this website [link](http://regex101.com/r/cU5lC2#PCRE) also helpful

Comment: There is a error in this code, when i try to match `fo foo foo`, it highlight `fo fo`o foo. The word should end with a space. Also I don't really understand `?:\s\1`. I know what they means separately.

Comment: If the word should end with a space, just add an additional word boundary `\b` at the end.